# apt-get vs. svn for installing stacks/packages

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is probably a bad question but I was wondering if there are any advantages to using one over the other (or even git or rosinstall)?
For example which is better out of the following two methods:

1. sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-laser-drivers
2. svn co https:://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/laser_drivers/trunk

best regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64490/apt-get-vs.-svn-for-installing-stacks/packages/) by [Abbi](https://answers.ros.org/users/5073/abbi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-06-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first one is the most easy method but the software version can be old. With the second method you can the most recent version but you have to compile yourself which is more work.
In the second method you have to check for updates and recompile yourself while with the first method you can just enter apt-get upgrade.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) on 2013-06-07**:
It really depends on what you want to do, and what your comfort level with installing from source is.  My default is to use `apt-get` unless I have a compelling reason to install from source, such as needing the very latest version of a package, for the reasons outlined in this answer.